# Same regex works in one script, doesn't work in another

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a simple regex (`'(\b) +-{1,} +(\b)'`) that is included in a script ([txt2tex.py](http://pastebin.com/mxHswNGC) ; line numbers 17 and 48 are the important ones) and can be given to another script ([multilineRegex.py](http://pastebin.com/ggBeCAvq) ; simply takes a regex to match against as it's 1st argument, replacement text as 2nd argument, and file name as 3rd) from the command line.

The regex doesn't match a given input text when evaluated inside txt2tex.py, but when I copy and paste it to the command line and invoke multilineRegex.py as follows, it works as expected:

```
multilineRegex.py '(\b) +-{1,} +(\b)' '---' input.txt
```

I noticed this discrepancy as I was playing around with regexes. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Used the following line to verify this behaviour:

```
Here's something - arbit for you to think of.
```

Details:

- Python: 2.7.5
- OS: OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Use raw string. Change `'(\b) +-{1,} +(\b)'` to `r'(\b) +-{1,} +(\b)'`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `\b` is a zero-length assertion, it doesn't make sens to capture it.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE You are right. Old habit + artefact of copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your shell interprets the `\b`s as control characters (backspace). You can demonstrate that by executing:

```
$ echo 'hello\bworld'
hellworld
```

When giving the regex to your script, escape it with an additional backslash:

```
multilineRegex.py '(\\b) +-{1,} +(\\b)' '---' input.txt
```

Comment: In any case, they are different regexes if you don't escape it when using it with `multilineRegex.py`.

Comment: In bash, nothing inside a pair of single quotes is expanded. If I was using double quotes they you may have been right.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My shell does interpret control characters there. But I see you have your answer.